# exclude string url in controller Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I wish my controller would work for everything except url 'abc'.

```
 /**
     * @Route(path="/api/{url}", name="test", requirements={"url"=".+"})
     */
    public function index(string $url)
    {
       ...
    }
```

How do I convert a regex url `"url"=".+"` for such that it will go to everyone except 'abc'?

Answer (score 1):

[Route parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters)

> The requirements option defines the [PHP regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) that route
> parameters must match for the entire route to match.

In your case, you want to allow everything but a specific string.

Just use a regular regex using `^((?!abc).)*$` if you do not want your url parameter to contain the string `abc`.

> Be aware that `abcde` or `dabc` will not work.

So your route would be

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/api/{url}", name="test", requirements={"url"="^((?!abc).)*$*"})
 */
public function index(string $url)
{
   //allow foo
   //allow bar
   //block abc
   //block fooabc
   //block barabc
}
```

If you want to allow string to contain abc then change your regex to `\b(?!abc\b)\w+`:

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/api/{url}", name="test", requirements={"url"="\b(?!abc\b)\w+"})
 */
public function index(string $url)
{
   //allow foo
   //allow bar
   //block abc
   //allow fooabc
   //allow barabc

}
```

Note that you can also add more words `\b(?!foo|bar\b)\w+`: